# Why is navigation drawer lagging at the first open?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

If I open up the navigation drawer in my app for the first time, it doesn't slide out, it waits and then shows it nearly full pulled out. Closing it and reopen the drawer shows normal sliding behaviour.

If I replace my drawer header backgroung image with just a color, it slides out like expected. My background image is a small JPG picture with about 50 KB.

How can I use a drawer header background picture without having the drawer lag at first open it?

Comment: How do you load your image?

Comment: with `android:background="@drawable/drawer` in the header layout file (RelativeLayout)

Comment: Set background image in background thread...

Comment: Also, try decompressing your image - see, for example, http://superuser.com/questions/454539/convert-image-to-uncompressed-png-from-the-command-line

Then take a look at the size. Remember that the image must be decompressed for display - the compressed size doesn't matter at all.
If your decompressed image is large, try reducing the color palette, or if appropriate, the dimensions of the compressed  image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem was that I had put the image into drawable folder. I moved it to drawable-xxxhdpi and any drawer lags have been solved.